# Unrooting an Android Phone, Help!

Tags: unrooting

My device is SHV-E160K

I kept deleting xbin and bin several times. It keeps on restoring and cannot delete file though I've already |remove root permission on king user|

How can I delete it? I cannot play the game that doesn't required root.

I cannot factory reset too because my upper volume button is broken

Help Please!!

Comment: You don't need a volume button to Factory Reset, it's an option in Settings.  You can also get to Recovery via `adb reboot recovery` and not needing a button combo.  Factory reset also doesn't unroot, however, and deleting the `bin` folder is a good way to make your ROM unusable.

Answer (score 1):

Are you rooted with SuperSU? If so, just go into the SuperSU app and select Full Unroot from settings. If that isn't the case, you could try [Universal Unroot](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.universal.unroot) as well.

You can likely keep root and play your game as well, with Xposed Framework and a module like [RootCloak](http://forum.xda-developers.com/xposed/modules/mod-rootcloak-completely-hide-root-t2574647) or without Xposed you can try using [RootCloak Plus](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.devadvance.rootcloakplus&hl=en) but non-Xposed methods of hiding root sometimes have a lower success rate.